# Determine the I and V of a logic gate

Tags: diodes, logic-gates

I have got this problem in my text book.

Determine V and I of the following circuit:
[image]

The result is I = 4mA and V = +1V (ideal diode)

How can I solve it using assumption process? Please help me out.

Comment: I=4A? I think you mean mA, 4A over 1kw is 1kV... Quite a lot. What diode models are you using? Ideal diodes? Or you have something like \$V_\gamma=0.6\text{ V}\$?

Comment: I recognize this picture any where. You got it from the Sedra/Smith textbook :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you use the ideal diode model, i.e. for positive currents the voltage drop is zero, for negative voltages the current flowing is zero.

You have three diodes, for a total of \$2^3=8\$ combinations of on/off. But we can get smarter.

If the top diode is on, V=3, but this is not possible because of middle and bottom diode. So top diode is off, and the same goes for the middle diode.

Now, we know that top and mid are off, so no current can flow. If also bot is off, no current flows anywhere, so V=5 because there is no drop in the resistor, but this is not possible because of the diodes, so bottom diode is on thus V=1. Using ohms law you calculate I as (5-1)/1k = 4mA.

For more complex circuits, what you usually do is start by assuming a combination of ons and offs, you try to solve the circuit, and if the solution is compatible with the status of the diodes, then you are done, otherwise you change the assumptions and start again.

Answer (score 0):

(assume ideal diode, Vd = 0V)

With the bottom diode conducting the other two diodes will be reverse biased (turned off) so the voltage output must be 1V.

This means there is a 4V drop across the 1k0 resistor giving a current of 4/1000 amps or 4mA.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a diode drop of 0.6V, the answer is 1.6V.

If the top diode is conducting only, then the output would be 3.6V, but situation would allow the other two diodes would have greater than a diode drop across them. If the middle diode were conducting, similarly, the lower diode would have more than a diode drop.

Therefore the only stable state given that schematic is that the voltage at the output point is 1.6V and only the lower diode is conducting.

There is 3.6V across the resistor, therefore there is a current of 3.6mA.